# Separate jar for EJB3 Entity classes

Tags: jpa, deployment, ejb-3.0, classnotfoundexception, glassfish-2.x

When I separate my EJB3 entities (annotated with @Entity) from my EJB Module and put them in a separate jar file, where should my Persistence.xml file go, in my EJB module or in my entities.jar? And how should I deploy the entities.jar file? It's not an EJB module since it doesn't have any EJBs, just JPA entities.

I'm using Glassfish and what I did was, put the entities.jar in the **/lib/applibs** directory and when deploying the EJB Module, i declared that it uses that library.

But the deployment fails with:

```
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pedra.Role
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [TOPLINK-28018] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.1 (Build b31g-fcs (10/19/2009))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: predeploy for PersistenceUnit [SignonPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [TOPLINK-30007] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.1 (Build b31g-fcs (10/19/2009))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while loading class: com.pedra.Role to check whether it implements @Entity, @Embeddable, or @MappedSuperclass.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pedra.Role
```

So why can't this class be found when it is in that entities.jar library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something that should be working.

I'd say:

- Check that your entity.jar is actually in lib/applibs;
- Check that when you deploy your EJB module you specify entity.jar correctly;
- Rebuild your jars;
- As funny as it may sound, undeploy your ejb module via Admin Console and restart Glassfish, and deploy your module again;

Answer (score 1):

In persistence.xml you can include jar containing entities as below. You can include jar by specifying relative or absolute path. You can include it along with other libraries in the application EAR & mention relative path, which is recommended.

`<jar-file>somejar.jar</jar-file>`

The configuration file should be in the META-INF in the EJB module.

Comment: I removed the list of class names and included the name of the jar as you suggested, but I get the same error. which is funny because it's like glassfish finds the jar, finds the annotated classes in that jar and then claims it couldn't find the class.